# Specify nameserver in a Lambda function from the HostedZone resource?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, sdk, aws-cloudformation

This is my Lambda function:

```
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
          import boto3
          var client = boto3.client('route53domains')
          response = client.update_domain_nameservers(
              DomainName='example.com',
              Nameservers=[
                  {
                      'Name': 'string',
                      ]
                  },
              ]
          )
```

What it should do is update the name servers for my registered domain on Route53 I just don't know how to specify the name servers to it, This is is a parth of Lambda resource in my CloudFormation stack and I have a resource HostedZone and I want to import `!GetAtt HostedZone.NameServers` to this function.

Doesn't HostedZone.NameServer return a list of 4 nameserver and the function asks for a string so I guess I need to add 4 strings. I'm lost.

Comment: Hi. I've noticed that you have a lot of questions with answers, but not a single one was accepted. Accepting good answers is a good practice as it stops people from making duplication questions. If the good answers are not accepted, duplicate questions are posted on the false assumption that existing answers are incorrect.

Comment: Usually they never answer or when they do their answer doesn't help at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Sub](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html) to pass in your `HostedZone.NameServers` into the lambda source code:

```
      Code:
        ZipFile: !Sub |
          import boto3
          var client = boto3.client('route53domains')
          response = client.update_domain_nameservers(
              DomainName='example.com',
              Nameservers=[
                  {
                      'Name': '${HostedZone.NameServers}',
                      ]
                  },
              ]
          )
```

The above is just an example. I'm not sure where exactly you want to use `HostedZone.NameServers`, but the correct way to refer to it is `${HostedZone.NameServers}` when `Sub` is used.

Comment: In the SDK documentation it says that this function will replace the current name servers of the registered domain but I am not sure if the output of HostedZone.NameServers will be a list and even if it is how will that fit in to variable that is a string in Python?

Comment: @KatranPlague It won't be a list, you have to parse it into the list yourself in your function